# Shapiro Wilk test of normality

Tags: distributions, anova, t-test, shapiro-wilk-test, jasp

I ran my data under JASP and the p-value for the shapiro wilk test of normality was <.001. How do I interpret this?

Comment: It means that your sample is large enough for normality to be rejected as a hypothesis. That doesn't mean that non-normality is a problem for you. If your analysis is of residuals, can you improve the model? If your analysis of one of your original variables, why did you do it? Not many techniques assume marginal normality of variables.

Answer (score -1):

One very basic but useful rule* to interpret this kind of test (normality, heteroskedasticity, autocorrelation) is to remember that when the p-value is less than 0.05, it means that something is "bad" is happening. Thus, if your p-value is less than 0.05, than means that the variable is not normal. However, the implications of that depends on the type of model you're using.

*Key exceptions: Coefficients test and Unit Root test (many) which are the opposite.